# Windows directory (%WINDIR%) on Windows Server 2003 Terminal Services returning wrong path

Tags: windows-server-2003, terminal-server, windows-terminal-services

I have a program installed on Windows Server 2003 (Terminal Services role) which should be reading its INI file from C:\Documents & Settings\$user\Windows, but has suddenly started reading it from C:\WIndows.

This is causing problems as it is used by multiple terminal services users simultaneously who each need different settings for the program. The program is now overwriting the settings as each user opens and closes the program.

The only info I can find is [this MDSN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724403) which states:

> "On a system that is running Terminal Services, each user has a unique Windows directory. The system Windows directory is shared by all users, so it is the directory where an application should store initialization and help files that apply to all users."

Theorectically then, %WINDIR% should be the users unique directory, but it is returning the system directory.

Unfortunately there is no support available for the program so I can't resolve it with the developer.

Is there a registry setting or anything else in Server 2003 that can restore the normal system behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

A restart of the server seems to have fixed the issue.